# Get Data Usage In bytes for mobile network interfaces separated (2G -3G - 4G)

Tags: android, android-networking, android-kernel

Is there a way to get the data traffic in bytes for mobile network interfaces separated (2G - 3G - 4G).

[TrafficStats](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html) Gives me the total usage of all mobile network interfaces with no separation between traffic used in every network interface (3G - 2G - 4G)

I have searched all over the network and i didn't find any thing related.

Comment: I also have same question, did u get any solution for your question?? if yes then please help me in this.